# Add action to scaffold generated controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created model, view and controller:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

Then I have added the method on Post controller:

```
def fill_default_data
  Post.fill_default_data
end
```

But when I have open http://localhost:3000/posts/fill_default_data in browser I get the error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
>   PostsController#show
>
> Couldn't find Post with
>   ID=fill_default_data

It looks like Rails don't see fill_default_data action and use show method.  How can I add new method to scaffold generated controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add the relevant route to your `config/routes.rb` file. If you currently have:

```
resources :posts
```

You should change that to:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get :fill_default_data
  end
end
```

That will generate a route that you can access through `/posts/fill_default_data`. Now your app is actually accessing the show action and filling in "fill_default_data" as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to add the method to a member rather than the collection, use the following:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get :fill_default_data, :as => 'fill_out_data'
  end
end
```

This using member if preferred if you are performing the action on a single post rather than on a collection of posts.  Also, the :as option generates named route helpers (stuff like *_path or *_url) in case you want them.